# How To confgure network printer with D-Link Dir655 router

Tags: brother-printer

I have an old printer (Brother mfc-7360n) which doesn't have built-in wi-fi or Bluetooth connectivity and I have successfully managed to make it wireless via the ethernet cable to my router, the problem is when have changed the place of the printer it's not longer possible to use the same router hence tried with a D-Link Dir655 without any success.
Can someone share knowledge about what might be issue as I could never see the printer over network from D-Link however it works pretty fine with previous one.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: When switching routers, sometimes it is helpful to setup the printer on the same ip address that it was using before, that way the computers can connect to it using the same settings. Do you have more information about the previous successful configuration? (i.e. the ip address, the printer's mac address) We can use that ip address and mac address to fill out the info on the dlink's configuration web interface. See Section 3 - Configuration - DHCP Reservation (page 38) in the dir-655 user guide http://www.gditechnology.com/manuals/Dlink-DIR655-manual.pdf

Comment: As i remember the IP address is 192.168.1.170 and port type is WSD, so I should reserve the default IP of D-Link to the same?

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that simply the IP of the printer changed?
Are you able to ping it?
You might have to check if the printer has a static IP from before which is outside the range of the current router.
I would strongly suggest making a DHCP reservation, especially if the printer is older. I've seen it multiple times when the static IP got erased during a reboot.

Comment: Well, since the Huawei router has a different IP 192.168.1.x than D-Link 192.168.0.x, so the printer is still having that IP address, you mean as suggested above in @iskyfire answer?

Comment: Generally - yes. It is not only "helpful" but necessary to change the IP to the correct address space. If you old router was 192.168.1.x and you new one is 192.168.0.x (on an assumed /24 network), the **can not** talk to each other (at least without further configuration.) = Completely different networks.
So you either change the static IP on the printer to your new network (i.e.192.168.0.170) or set it to DHCP and find the new address on the router web page. From there you should be able to grab the MAC address (or try command line `arp -g`) and create a DHCP reservation.

Comment: While I agree with that, but even deleting the printer and connecting it to new router is still not discoverable!

Comment: Can you check the IP address on the printer itself? (Print settings or via display?)

Comment: No the printer is pretty old and doesn't have such options